# PHP Zend Controller Plugin getting called twice

Tags: php, zend-framework

I noticed that my plugins are getting called twice. I know this for a fact because in my ViewSetup plugin it registers the headtitle, and the title contains the same content twice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to an exception being thrown, which called subsequently the errorcontroller after the initial request.

Answer (score 4):

Your most likely duplicating the calls to `preDispatch` or `postDispatch`. These methods are called within a loop of the `Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch` for every request that is not already dispatched. That means a cloned request with dispatch set to false and even using `$this->_forward` in a controller will cause another execution of these methods.

Try changing to `routeStartup` or `routeShutdown`. Those will normally only run once for the application. If you absolutely need to run `pre/postDispatch`, you should keep track in your plugin either with a count or by keeping a copy of the original request and checking if it's already in your plugin.

The other possibility is that your adding the plugin twice. This is likely if you are adding via the application.ini and also have `registerPlugin` in your Bootstrap or other script. If your adding the plugin twice by accident, keeping a count of how many times you run the `pre/postDispatch` will not help.

Comment: You saved me! I was appending the module name to the layout path and every time it was added twice. Now everything's alright :)

Answer (score 0):

Dump a `debug_backtrace()` into a file and you can see where each call is coming from.